# Redux обновить в ...state после action и записать в другой action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
const initialState = {
    firstClick: null, 
    secondClick: null
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        //тут все работает отлично
        case actionTypes.TAG_CLICK:
            return {
                ...state,
                firstClick: action.clicked.customval, 

            };
        case actionTypes.CONTENT_CLICK:
            return {
                ...state,
                //мне нужно записать сюда данные, которые были получены после TAG_CLICK
                secondClick: {...state.secondClick, ...state.firstClick}, 

            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Оба action в разных компонентах. Простым языком: когда я кликаю на тег в одном компоненте, его **содержимое** попадает в reducer. Во втором компоненте я тоже делаю клик и **содержимое** попадает во второй компонент

Comment: зачем вам записывать в `secondClick` что-то из `firstClick` если у вас и так есть доступ к `firstClick`????

Comment: @ThisMan это как один из тщетных вариантов, я туда писал уже все, что знал..

Answer (score 0):

Ответ был слишком прост, чтобы додуматься до него изначально...

```
secondClick: state.firstClick,
```

Comment: зачем? зачем дублировать данные?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте экшоны для изменения firstClick и secondClick в нужной компоненте друг за другом. Хоть в 1000 компонентах используйте, но таким образом